# how to make database field for password in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring

For user registration i have two fields password and confirm password.

And in spring i have to bind with java bean.

I am confused how can I make database field.

Comment: Obligatory warning to not store passwords in the database.

Comment: Please can you rephrase your question!

Comment: @jonnii - "to not store passwords in database". I think you meant: "to not store *plaintext* passwords in database".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply take one field with `String` type in DB and two in bound model.

In your registration service or validation check for both.